# Access other AWS VPC Instances but OpenVPN server

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, routing, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I've configured OpenVPN server on Bastion instance in public subnet on  AWS VPC. Right now, I have access private IP address of  that instance with my OpenVpn client, but we want to **access EC2 instances running in other private subnets** in the VPC.

Here is my server.conf file:

```
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp


;dev tap
dev tun


;dev-node MyTap


ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server.key 

dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh.pem


;topology subnet


server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

;client-config-dir ccd
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
route 10.10.12.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.52.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.51.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "route 10.10.12.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.51.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.52.0 255.255.255.0"




;learn-address ./script


;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"


client-to-client

#keepalive 10 120



tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-256-CBC

user nobody
group nobody

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

Since my networking knowledge is not on proper level, if anyone has an idea how to solve this, i would be very greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have several Mikrotik Cloud RouterOS as OpenVPN server in my VPC, and it also took me a while to get it working.

I don't have a clear picture of your infrastructure and what is your current problem, but **I assume that your client can already connect to the OpenVPN server but cannot reach other private EC2 servers.**

I noticed that your client IP pool (10.8.0.0/24) is different than the OpenVPN server internal IP (10.10.0.0/16).  This complicates VPC routing because your VPC route table has no idea what subnet is 10.8.0.0/24 and where to route the corresponding traffic.

The way I solved this was to apply NAT so my client traffic (Say IP 10.8.0.100) would be masqueraded as the OpenVPN server (Say IP 10.10.0.100) when packets leave the OpenVPN server. This way the private EC2 server will always route through the OpenVPN server.

Several things you also need to check:

1. EC2 Security group is allowing the traffic
2. VPC Subnets are associated with your route table
3. VPC Route table has the corresponding routes setup
4. EC2 Source/Destination checks is disabled if NAT is happening

An alternative solution might be setting the route table so that all 10.8.0.0/24 traffic is sent to your OpenVPN server, but I never got that working so good luck if you go this route.

Comment: Thanks @Victor Wong, i've solved Yesterday by setting custom client subnet in VPC range. Also, I didnt disable Source/Destination checks.