# AWS OpenVPN server - accessing other instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn, unbound

Happy new year!

I've just set up an AWS account and have three instances at the moment (one is for a Certificate Authority so is largely irrelevant). Both are running on Ubuntu 22.04, one is hosting an OpenVPN server, where the set-up was easier than I remembered.

We're also running a custom web portal solution which is staff only, as it'll contain confidential customer information. The problem is that, despite configuring CIDRs, Unbound, EC2 security groups etc, we cannot find a way to allow HTTPS access without it being available on the clearnet. Obviously this creates a bit of a security risk, so am against doing this.

Followed the guide at [Access other AWS VPC Instances but OpenVPN server](https://serverfault.com/questions/929014/access-other-aws-vpc-instances-but-openvpn-server) but not so much help. Any ideas? If you need anything too, I'm happy to share whatever I can to get this working! Thank you so much.

**UPDATE:** It seems like a routing table issue but I am struggling to figure out why it won't let me amend it. It says that the IP address isn't in the CIDR subnet, although it is within the block. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a text/diagram showing how you're trying to access the web portal? e.g. workstation -> vpn -> openvpn server -> portal? what subnets etc are in use?

Comment: @shearn89 so it's PC -> OpenVPN/Unbound -> VPC, all on one subnet -> portal. It feels simple enough, but I think I'm forgetting the obvious (I am the novice here, but start-ups aren't cheap to run!). 

I'm thinking the error lies in the route tables through the VPC, so I'm gonna keep going through that. Thank you again!

Comment: Update, it is seeming like a route table issue. For some reason, I cannot save the direct private IP /32 to direct to the instance. I am officially confused. Sorry to bother!